# How can I select both specific columns and wildcards in one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT orders.user_id as orderuserid , *
FROM submissions
INNER JOIN orders
ON orders.listing_id=submissions.listing_id  where  orders.user_id=
```

Comment: Put the star first, e.g. `SELECT *, orders.user_id, ...`

Comment: Don't put the star anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is near correct, but the wildcard must come before any other fields. The correct query would be:

```
SELECT *, orders.user_id as orderuserid
FROM submissions
INNER JOIN orders
ON orders.listing_id=submissions.listing_id  where  orders.user_id=
```

Comment: Yes Thanks very much Damein and Tim

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want the same column returned twice?

Aliasing the asterisk also works:

```
SELECT orders.user_id as orderuserid , submissions.*, orders.*
FROM submissions
INNER JOIN orders
```

Of course, you shouldn't use `*` at all.